# Issues getting Flash Builder 4.6 Air app to compile correctly with Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: air, flash-builder

Basically the Air app compiles with Flash Builder 4.6 using the Flex 4.6 sdk.  But when I open the exact same project in Flash Builder 4.7, it wants to compile it with the Air 3.4 sdk.

And, unlike in FB 4.6, FB 4.7 doesn't give any options to change the sdk under project properties, ActionScript Compiler. no toggle buttons for Use Default SDK and Use a specific SDK.  FB 4.7 just has "This project will use AIR SDK 3.4" at the top without any options.

FB 4.6 and FB 4.7 are on two different machines.  One possible option would be to load 4.6 on the one with just 4.6, but it's part of a new Creative Cloud license and there don't seem to be any options at Adobe to download previous versions of FB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a strange thing, right :) ?

But the solution is quite simple:

- Close the project.
- Go to the projects folder and open **.actionScriptProperties** (on Mac this is hidden)
- change 'useFlashSDK="true"' to 'useFlashSDK="false"' .
- Save and close
- Open your project again.

Voilá, you can choose the SDK again :)

Comment: Could you accept it as correct answer, so that others can find it easier :) ?